# How to query microsoft graph explorer?

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, graph-explorer

There are various requests and responses: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.
I want to call GET https://graph.microsoft.com/drive/root/children
from python scripts after providing client id and client secret

I want to modify some files in my sharepoint using Microsoft Graph Explorer using python.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start with the [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) module.

`requests.get()` should do what you want.